# sqllite database lock(5) in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, locking

I have a problem with Android sqlite database, I get the database lock  exception only on jellybean version(not yet checked for kitkat).Below shown is the logcat file for the exception.

```
04-14 18:40:02.517: E/SQLiteLog(3917): (5) database is locked
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.assets.screens/databases/AssetDB.db'.
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1012)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:757)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:443)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:417)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:323)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:217)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:464)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:186)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:926)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at com.example.assets.utils.AssetDB.getAssetData(AssetDB.java:169)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17343)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-14 18:40:02.524: E/SQLiteDatabase(3917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917): Couldn't open AssetDB.db for writing (will try read-only):
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1012)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:757)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:443)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:417)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:323)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:217)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:464)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:186)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:926)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
04-14 18:40:02.548: E/SQLiteOpenHelper(3917):   at com.example.assets.utils.AssetDB.getAssetData(AssetDB.java:169)
04-14 18:40:05.087: W/System.err(3917): Error:null
```

Below is my database code. The db lock issue happens only for jellybean. I am missing on some checks for database. Database reading happens on button click, after the first click db gets lock..

```
public class AstDB {
    static SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB.db";
    private static Context mContext;
    private static AsDatabase database;

    public AsDB(Context ctx) {
        this.mContext = ctx;

    }

    public static class AsDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static synchronized AsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
            if (database == null) {
                database = new AsDatabase(context);
            }

            return database;
        }

        public AsDatabase(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            InputStream mngr = null;
            String line = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                mngr = mContext.getAssets().open("TABLE_QUERIES.txt");
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mngr));

                line = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (line != null) {
                db.execSQL(line);
                System.out.println("table created");
                try {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    // ---opens the database---
    public DB open() throws SQLException {
        db = AsDatabase.getInstance(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // ---closes the database---
    public void close() {
        AsDatabase.getInstance(mContext).close();
    }

    public void insertAssetData() {

        InputStream mngr = null;

        try {
            mngr = mContext.getAssets().open("INSERT_ALL_QUERIES.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mngr));

        String line = null;

        try {
            line = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * db.beginTransaction();
         * 
         * while (line != null) {
         * 
         * try { db.execSQL(line); line = reader.readLine(); //
         * db.setTransactionSuccessful(); } catch (IOException e) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated catch block // db.endTransaction();
         * e.printStackTrace(); }
         * 
         * } db.setTransactionSuccessful(); db.endTransaction();
         */

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while (line != null) {

                db.execSQL(line);
                line = reader.readLine();

            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            db.endTransaction();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.endTransaction();



    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAssetData(ArrayList<String> queryList,
            ArrayList<String> columnList) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        ArrayList<String> resultArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {

            db = AsDatabase.getInstance(mContext).getReadableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            for (int i = 0; i < queryList.size(); i++) {

                cursor = db.rawQuery(queryList.get(i), null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //
                        System.out.println("allIndex="
                                + cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnList
                                        .get(i)));
                        System.out.println("allData="
                                + cursor.getString(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(columnList.get(i))));
                        resultArray.add(i, cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(columnList.get(i))));

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();

            db.endTransaction();
            AsDatabase.getInstance(mContext).close();



        }

        return resultArray;
    }


}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated